# Counts on Changed data

Tags: sql

I have a data where i need to give the counts of the rows for which the confidence code changed.

Input data:

```
ID Date  ReMatchConfidence OrgMatch
1  2017      101             45
2  2017      101             88
3  2017      103             35
4  2016      104             66
5  2016      104             66
6  2017      104             66
7  2016      88              14
8  2017      88              25
```

Output:

```
Data                   2017 2016
Change from 45 to 101   1   0
Change from 88 to 101   1   0
Change from 35 to 103   1   0
Change from 66 to 104   1   2
Change from 14 to 88    0   1
Change from 25 to 88    1   0
```

Comment: Most people here want formatted text, not images. (Or, even worse, links to images.)

Comment: You can just group by Orgmatch and Rematchconfidence, you then need to create string based on these, and pivot by date.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT CONCAT('Change from ', OrgMatch, ' to ', ReMatchConfidence) AS Data,
Count(IF(Date = '2017', 1, NULL)) as '2017', 
Count(IF(Date = '2016', 1, NULL)) as '2016' 
FROM tables GROUP BY OrgMatch, ReMatchConfidence;
```

Answer (score 0):

A little modification to Daria's query. Works in SQL Server

```
SELECT CONCAT('Change from ', OrgMatch, ' to ', [RefMatch Confidence]) AS Data,
Count(CASE WHEN [Date] = '2017' THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) as '2017', 
Count(CASE WHEN [Date] = '2016' THEN 1 ELSE NULL END ) as '2016' 
FROM t1 GROUP BY OrgMatch, [RefMatch Confidence];
```